# Calcuate time duration in different row and different column?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I want to calculate time duration in different row and different column. This is my sample data:

[image: sample data]

`'STATUSIN'(in second row) - 'STATUSOUT'(in first row)` And i wanna put the output in 'LOSTTIME' column

For example:

```
08:07:53 - 08:06:22  = 00:01:31 (OUTPUT)
```

and this is my code to display data from database:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrDAILYDATAWH" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>NIP</th>
                            <th>NAME</th>
                            <th>DEPARTMENT</th>
                            <th>IN</th>
                            <th>OUT</th>
                            <th>LOSTTIME</th>
                       </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <th><%# Eval("NIP") %></th>
                    <td><%# Eval("NAME") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("DEPARTMENT") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("STATUSIN") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("STATUSOUT") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("LOSTTIME") %></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

This is the code on backend:

```
protected void BindDAILYDATWHARptr() {
  String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MANHOURConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS)) {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM DAILYDATAWH", con)){
      using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) {
        DataTable dtDaily = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dtDaily);
        rptrDAILYDATAWH.DataSource = dtDaily;
        rptrDAILYDATAWH.DataBind();
      }    
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens if `'STATUSOUT' <= 'STATUSIN'`?

Comment: As a general rule, avoid using `SELECT *`, and instead specify the column names. This will help avoid errors if you reorder/rename/remove columns, because then your query will break and you'll notice you need to change your code much earlier.

Comment: i'm sorry, i've corrected my questioned

Comment: What if one user has three statuses on a given day?

Comment: @SalmanA this data just show for 1 day,  so the data it's filtered for 1 day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you basically need is `LAG`. Read this [article](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/) for more inforamtion. This works for `SQL Server 2012 onwards`. Once you get prev status in, you can apply required condition during runtime in `C#`

```
SELECT NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT, STATUSIN, STATUSOUT, LAG(STATUSIN,1) OVER(ORDER BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT) PREVSTATUSIN FROM DAILYDATAWH
```

Another solution for `SQL Server 2008` is using `Self JOIN`

```
SELECT a.NIP, a.NAME, a.DEPARTMENT, a.STATUSIN, a.STATUSOUT, 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(TIME, b.STATUSIN  - a.STATUSOUT), 108) LOSTTIME
FROM DAILYDATAWH a 
  LEFT JOIN DAILYDATAWH b ON a.ID = b.ID - 1 AND a.NIP = b.NIP AND a.NAME = b.NAME AND a.DEPARTMENT = b.DEPARTMENT
```

OUTPUT

[image]

To Update `LOSTTIME` you should do something like this

```
UPDATE a SET a.LOSTTIME = CONVERT(TIME, b.STATUSIN  - a.STATUSOUT)
FROM DAILYDATAWH a 
  LEFT JOIN DAILYDATAWH b ON a.ID = b.ID - 1 AND a.NIP = b.NIP AND a.NAME = b.NAME AND a.DEPARTMENT = b.DEPARTMENT
```

Comment: Thankyou, but there is an another option without using LAG? Because i used sql server 2008, and the LAG function  just worked in sql server 2012

Comment: I'm not sure this solution addresses the condition mentioned.

Comment: @DeaAnanda `LAG()` (and its counterpart `LEAD()`) are syntactic sugar for `JOIN`. You can join the table to itself with an offset in the ID to achieve the same goal.

Comment: @DeaAnanda, i have add another solution using `self join` to get previous record. hope this helps

Comment: @TsahiAsher, yes you are right. getting previous record is challenge here, once you get the previous value, adding if condition will be easier.

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla Thank you for helping me, but there is an error 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'A1' to data type int.' because `NIP` type is nvarchar

Comment: @DeaAnanda, it was a typo. it should be `a.ID = b.ID + 1`

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla thankyou, it's work. but, it's not the output that i meant. it's doesn't calculate the datetime duration. please check again my question and see the sample data, and for Example : 08:07:53 - 08:06:22 = 00:01:31 (OUTPUT). it's calculate different column and different row

Comment: @DeaAnanda, check the updated post now. Have added `LOSTTIME` to the query

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla thank you so much!!:) it's work for me, but how to insert the value in column 'LOSTTIME'?

Comment: LOSTTIME is calculated by select query. we need not insert any value to this column.

Comment: @KrishnaMuppalla but, the value can't saved in column 'LOSTTIME' and in the database, right? how to save that value in column 'LOSTTIME'? not just select query

Comment: i've try to update the value with query `UPDATE
DAILYDATAWH AS A
SET
A.LOSTTIME = CONVERT(TIME, b.STATUSIN - a.STATUSOUT)
FROM
LEFT JOIN DAILYDATAWH b ON a.ID = b.ID - 1 AND a.NIP = b.NIP AND a.NAME = b.NAME AND a.DEPARTMENT = b.DEPARTMENT` but its error and not work

Comment: @DeaAnanda, have updated the post to include `UPDATE`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much it's very helpful:)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server you can refer below script as per your requirement.

SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) AS 'First_date', GETDATE() AS 'Second_date',
        FORMAT(DATEADD(ss,DATEDIFF(ss,'2020-02-10 10:30:00.143', '2020-02-11 14:22:20.683' ),0),'hh:mm:ss') AS 'Difference'[image]

Comment: thank you for helping me, but it's not the output that i meant

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have `LOSTTIME` in data you can calculate within repeater:

Change:

```
<td><%# Eval("LOSTTIME") %></td>
```

to

```
<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("STATUSOUT")) > Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("STATUSIN")) ? Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("STATUSOUT")).Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("STATUSIN"))).ToString() : "-" %>
```

Comment: Thankyou, i'm sorry i've corrected my question. i wanna put the output in 'LOSTTIME' column

Comment: You dont need to `<%# Eval("LOSTTIME") %>`, you can do this within repeater `<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("STATUSOUT")) > Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("STATUSIN")) ? Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("STATUSOUT")).Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("STATUSIN"))).ToString() : "-" %>` does not work for you?

Comment: thankyou, it's work. but, it's not the output that i meant. please check again my question and see the sample data, and for Example : `08:07:53 - 08:06:22  = 00:01:31 (OUTPUT)`. it's calculate different column and different row

Comment: i don't meant to calculate in same row, i meant calculate in different row, please check again the image in question for sample data. calculate `'STATUSIN'(in second row) - 'STATUSOUT'(in first row)`